# insert a character at x,y,z positions in a string

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, text-processing

I need to insert "-" minus sign in below string after 2 characters then after 3 characters like:

`mystring="223334444"`

and the desired output be like:
`22-333-4444`

I am able to insert characters at fixed length by following below question,

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5980/how-do-i-insert-a-space-every-four-characters-in-a-long-line

but in my case, the splitting is not static (not after each nth positions but after x,y,z positions), I need an expression to do the job using sed.

**Update**
I am able to achieve the required format using multiple sed commands like : 
`echo 111111111 | sed  's/.\{2\}/&-/' |  sed  's/.\{6\}/&-/'`

but I need to know how I can I achieve it using a single expression

**Adding more information// sorry that I missed it earlier**

the output `22-333-444` will be used in some searching (using grep) and I will potentially have to do thousands of these conversions and then do the searching on the output strings, so here processing speed/optimization would also be desirable.

**Adding information about searching part as requested in comments**

inputfile sample:

```
135311046
135310897
135311354
135310944
125312732
125222083
415211804
415222255
415204163
415206020
```

I am reading this file line by line in a while loop, in a variable `line`

what I want to do is to convert this string `135311046` to `13-531-1046` and then do grep on a file.

I am currently using below substitution 
`grep $(echo $line | sed 's/.\{2\}/&-/' |  sed  's/.\{6\}/&-/')  datafile.txt`

datafile contains data like this:

```
Line1.P2.ON28.C1.P1.FL1,12-522-2083
Line1.P1.ON19.C1.P1.FL1,12-522-2112
Line1.P1.ON34.C1.P1.FL1,12-530-2766
Line1.P2.ON15.C1.P1.FL1,12-531-1041
Line1.P2.ON15.C1.P3.FL1,12-531-1041
Line1.P2.ON15.C1.P4.FL1,12-531-1041
Line1.P1.ON39.C1.P1.FL1,12-531-1094
Line1.P2.ON26.C1.P1.FL1,12-531-2732
Line1.P1.ON57.C1.P1.FL1,12-533-4019
```

so my main requirement is to do the conversion in a nice/compact manner and since these are thousands of lines I need to search in another file, it needs to be fast/optimized

Comment: For your information added later about searching part further. I would like to request you to mention your complete requirement in your post and do let us know the sample of Input_file and expected sample output too(including your all requirements of substitutions and search etc) and let us know then.

Comment: the strings are fixed length i.e. 9 digits each, but would contain random numbers so not fixed to 2s or 3s but rather any digit [0-9] can appear at any position.

Comment: Position vice its ok(mine first solution of anubhava sir's solution handles it), major question was about that search part? Which you added later in your post, kindly add more details on it in your post and let us know.(If you could give us complete picture of your requirement we MAY try to do within single command itself rather than multiple commands using)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk:

```
$ echo $mystring | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""}{$2=$2 "-";$5=$5 "-"}1'
22-333-4444
```

Explained:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=""   # field separators to null, ie. each char on an individual field
}{
    $2=$2 "-"   # set dashes to all the right places
    $5=$5 "-"
}1'             # output
```

Succesfully tested on GNU awk, mawk, Busybox awk and BWK awk version 20121220.

**Update**: *what I want to do is to convert this string `135311046` to `13-531-1046` and then do grep on a file*. All in one awk program:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    OFS=""
}
NR==FNR {
    $2=$2 "-";$5=$5 "-"
    a[$0]
    next
}
$NF in a' FS="" input FS="," data
```

Output:

```
Line1.P2.ON28.C1.P1.FL1,12-522-2083
Line1.P2.ON26.C1.P1.FL1,12-531-2732
```

Succesfully tested on GNU awk, mawk and Busybox awk. Failed on BWK awk version 20121220.

Comment: You should mention that will only work in some awks since the effect of setting FS to null  is undefined by POSIX so some awks will split the string into chars, others won't split the string at awll, etc. For portability to all awks use `$0=substr($0,1,2) "-" substr($0,3,3) "-" substr($0,6)` instead of `FS=""; ... $2=$2 "-"; $5=$5 "-"`.

Answer (score 3):

***EDIT:*** Since OP has edited post with complete requirement so adding solution as per it now.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[substr($0,1,2)"-"substr($0,3,3)"-"substr($0,6)]
  next
}
($NF in a)'   Input_file1  FS=","  Input_file2
```

It should work in any `awk` IMHO. Output will be as follows.

```
Line1.P2.ON28.C1.P1.FL1,12-522-2083
Line1.P2.ON26.C1.P1.FL1,12-531-2732
```

---

---

***1st Solution:*** Could you please try following. Here I am placing `-` after first 2 characters then after 3 characters. Here I am using `sed`'s capability to store the values into memory by using `\(..\)` which means letting `sed` know to keep 1st 2 chars into memory(which later could be accessed by using \1) similarly we can create more memory place holders and can access them with their numbers later while substitution part.

```
mystring="223334444"
echo "$mystring" | sed 's/\(..\)\(...\)\(....\)/\1-\2-\3/'
```

***2nd solution:*** Or if you want to substitute all 2's and all 3's in a string's value(this will not depend upon place of 2s and 3s it will simply substitute them in everywhere in string) then try following.

```
echo "$mystring" | sed -E 's/2+|3+/&-/g'
```

Output will be as follows.

```
22-333-4444
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you can do this in `bash` without any regex:

```
mystring="223334444"
echo "${mystring:0:2}-${mystring:2:3}-${mystring:5}"
```

```
22-333-4444
```

Comment: it is not working as expected, as you see the output should be `22-333-444`.

Comment: Oh sorry there was a typo Please check updated answer now.